# Postgres regex rowwise on large comma separated text string

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, jsonb

I have created a table with various columns to filter on such as id, date, and regex_col in the examples below. The goal of this database is to allow the user to filter appropriately for the json_b_value they are looking for. The current database is not very large around ~100M rows.

I have taken the row names out of json_b_value to create the regex_col with the thought process that I can index the regex_col in some way and allow users to regex search for the json_b_value they are looking for. The text in the regex_col is stored as a large comma separated string, with the number of words ranging from 10 - 150.

```
id   | date |          regex_col           |     json_b_value
1      2019   'some','stuff','to','search'         json
2      2018   'different','stuff','other'          json
3      2019     'lots','of','stuff'                json
```

The user will interact and search this column using a selectize.js dropdown. A separate table takes all of the comma separated words from regex_col and binds them all together rowwise, like below. Then words matching their search will populate as they type, any words not matching anything will result in a null.

```
search_words |
'some'
'stuff'
'to'
'search'
```

What would be an effective way to index the regex_col? Is this the optimal way to do this, should I even be creating the regex_col or should I be trying to optimize around the json_b_value?

example of json value for id 1 below

```
[{"regex_col":"some","current":100,"previous":200},{"regex_col":"stuff","current":200,"previous":400},{"regex_col":"to","current":300,"previous":600},{"regex_col":"search","current":400,"previous":800}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be a lot of factors, but in most cases the best solution is the folowing:

Create a new table with two columns

```
id, term
```

and then populate

```
1    'some'
1    stuff'
1    'to'
1    'search'
2    'different' 
2    'stuff' 
2    'other' 
3    'lots'        
3    'of'        
3    'stuff'
```

Now put an index on this table and you are GTG